# Xcode is checking a file for ARC readiness even though it was not selected in conversion tool

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am converting my project to arc (Edit>Convert to Arc) in Xcode.

I have unselected the file JRActivityObject.m however it comes back with ARC errors for this file.  I have explicitly de-selected this file in the list so I cannot understand why Xcode is checking this.

Any ideas?

> Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type
>   'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged
>   cast
>
> 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode

---

I cleaned the project and deleted the build files and the error went away now.

However I am still having this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596905/converting-project-to-arc-xcode-finds-release-retain-issue-with-files-before-it).

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file `JRActivityObject.m` has been compile under ARC mode even though unselected.

I suggest you to flag this file to compiler that unable in ARC mode with

**Click your project name > Build Phases Tab > Compile Sources Section > choose `JRActivityObject.m` and press return > type "*-fno-objc-arc*" and click Done.**

Now your `JRActivityObject.m` will be not compile in ARC Mode. Hope it helps you.